# Symfony2: AJAX request returns full page html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I'm trying to get a simple AJAX request to work in Symfony2. It seems that the request is never reaching the controller. Instead of alerting the number '123', the AJAX request returns the HTML of the current page (index.html.twig). I have a feeling that since the pattern of the AJAX route is pointing to the current page I am on, the AJAX response is being filled with the output of the current page rather than getting the response from the Controller. Is there any way that I can get just the value from the Controller? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my Twig template (index.html.twig):

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <a href="123" class="test">Test</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts '@AppBundle/js/jquery.js' %}
       <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
            jQuery('.test').on('click', function(){
                var id = jQuery(this).attr('href');

                jQuery.post('{{path('task_ajax')}}',               
                    {data: id}, 
                    function(response){
                        alert(response);
                    }
                );
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my routing.yml file:

```
task_ajax:
    pattern:  /jobs
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Ajax:task }
    requirements:
        _method:  POST
```

Here is my controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; 

class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    public function taskAction() {
        $request = $this->container->get('request');        
        $data = $request->query->get('data');

        return new Response($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check `routing` order. Move Ajax route to first place.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but I'm still having the same problem

Comment: also to get the Post from request you have to do : $request->request->get('data');  $request->query->get('data') this is GET method of your request

Comment: You can for experiment return just string. return ('my string') ; and if you'll see whole page, you need to check that you request matches with AjaxController route. And CHECK order of your routes in routing.yml I think your request matches with wrong route

Comment: I tried with a string and I still get the whole page. Should the pattern of the AJAX route in routing.yml point to the same page that I am on?

Comment: @G-SCO move your ajax route to first place in the route file

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work either. I've noticed that in the dev toolbar at the bottom of symfony, it says 'No AJAX requests yet.' even though I just clicked the link and it display all of the HTML in the alert box

Comment: I figured it out and it was a really simple fix. The routing order was part of the problem so i'll mark your answer as correct. The main problem was that I was using pattern instead of path in the routing.yml file. Glad I got it all sorted out, thanks for your help!

Comment: @G-SCO it's have to work. At least after change routing order try clear cache. It's seems like your route pattern matches with not Ajax route. Anyway I have nothing to say something else.